# IBM Worklight - UTF-8 encoding isn't working as expected

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing an Android application with IBM Worklight. It uses HTML5, Javascript and CSS. My IDE is Eclipse Indigo.

My question is, why is only one variation of string declaration correctly displaying the string?

This is the JavaScript code. The script file is UTF-8 encoded so are all the files in the project (I changed this in the properties of the file in eclipse):

```
function setLangGerman() {
    Messages = {
        pstHeader : "%C3%9Cbungen",
        btUebersicht : encodeURIComponent("Übersicht"),
        btStart : "Überhaupt nicht",
        btOptions : "Optionen",

        xDelConfirm : "Willst Du die Serie wirklich löschen?"
    };
}

function setLangGeneral() {
    var lang = localStorage.getItem(g_lsLang);

    if(lang === "de")
    {
        setLangGerman();
    }
    else
    {
        setLangEnglish();
    }

    $(".translate").each(function(index, element) {
        element = $(element);
        var elementId = element.attr("id");
        element.text(decodeURIComponent(Messages[elementId]));
    });
}
```

You see my attempt to use umlauts in 3 variations (`pstHeader`, `btUebersicht`, `btStart`). Only the `pstHeader` is displayed correctly on my Android device. But when I debug in Chrome all 3 variations are displayed correctly. I cannot post screenshots yet, but I hope you understand.

To complete my question this is the main.html file. It's also UTF-8 encoded:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
...
    <div data-role="page" id="pageStart">
        <div data-role="header" id="header">
            <h3 id="pstHeader" class="translate">Billardübungen</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
            <a href="#pageOverview" data-role="button" id="btUebersicht" class="translate">Übersicht</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="btStart" class="translate">Starte neue Serie</a>
            <a href="#pageOptions" data-role="button" id="btOptions" class="translate">Optionen</a>
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of a defect that was corrected in Worklight 6.0.

Make sure that the generated project files in `android\native` are also in UTF-8 formatting.